# Pushing a UITableViewController with custom animation always animates UINavigationItem Title

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I use the following code as an extension to `UINavigationController` to push a view controller with a custom animation:

```
@implementation UINavigationController (PushAnimation)

- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController*)controller  withTransition:(UIViewAnimationTransition)transition
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [self pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];        
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:transition forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

@end
```

With caching enabled, I get a strange animation behaviour when pushing a `UITableViewController`. The title of the pushed view appears after the custom animation is completed. With the transition style `UIViewAnimationTransitionNone`, it becomes clear that the title itself is animated. It is moved from the top left corner of the screen into the center of the `UINavigationBar`.

With caching disabled, this animation is not visible due to its speed, but the frame rate drops significantly.

How can I prevent the title from being animated?

Comment: I think that the animation of the title is happening in the `UINavigationBar` code. An idea would be to subclass that as well and change it's default behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick update what my fix was in the end. It was not possible to override the default behaviour of `UINavigationBar`, since iOS uses private API to implement the animation. So I ended up removing all animations on the `UINavigationBar`, and its various subviews, using the following code:

```
[self.navigationBar.layer removeAllAnimations];
for (UIView *view in self.navigationBar.subviews) {
    [view.layer removeAllAnimations];
    for (UIView *sub in view.subviews) {
        [sub.layer removeAllAnimations];
    }
}
```

It is important that this is called after `[self pushViewController:controller animated:NO];`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are *animating* whole view `self.view`. `self.view` contains the view controller as well as the `UINavigationBar`. So you probably will have to get all subviews of `self.view` and then animate only the `view` pertaining to your view controller.

Comment: Well, I want to animate the navigation bar too, since I want the whole screen to change, not just the content below the UINavigationBar. The problem is, that I not seem to be able to disable the default navigation of the UINavigationbar.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to customize your navigation transition animation in a very straightforward way:

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.5;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn; //kCATransitionPush; //kCATransitionReveal; //kCATransitionFade; 
//transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight; //transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft; //transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop; //transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

and the same thing for push.

**Make sure to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`
 in your class, and also add the framework to your project

> target > Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries > the "+" button >
>   QuartzCore.framework

.**